# Is your vault saved locally or in the cloud?

Tags: android, fallout-shelter

I have the android version of fallout shelter and am logged in through google play. Is my save game data on my device or is it saved in the cloud associated with my logged in account?

The reason I ask is because the game is currently crashing in the loading screen (before I even choose vault) and I am wondering if it is safe to wipe it from my device and reinstall to see if that fixes or if I will lose my vault by doing this.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

<s>Your vault is **not** synchronised in the cloud.</s>

### *Edit : since patch 1.2, it can be synchronized.*

You have to enable Cloud save for your Vault in the load screen like so:

[image: enabling cloud saving]

### Manual backup

If you want to reinstall the game without using the cloud save, you can first make a copy of your save file - it is located in `/Android/data/com.bethsoft.falloutshelter/files/VaultX.sav`, either on your SD card or in the internal memory.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that was the case. The save game location is really helpful though. I'll have to see if I can get it backed up...

Comment: You should be able to find it with your computer file explorer. I *think* you don't even need a rooted phone, but I have none and cannot test.

Comment: I found I have an app called "My files" which allowed me to browse files. Clearing out the data is allowing fallour to load further than before. Lets hope copying the file back will do the job. :)

Comment: Sadly it looks like my save game file is bugged in some way. When copied out and data cleared its like when I first installed it. If I copy the file in at this point it lets me get to the "enter vault"/"select vault" screen but either option crashes the app, I assume both actually look in the save game file and something in there it doesn't like very much and crashes. On the plus side my main goal was to build a nukacola bottling plant and even though it wasn't levelled I did manage that so no great loss. I doubt I'll bother restarting though. :(

Comment: Sad to learn that. Since your game was crashing before, thouh, your file *might* indeed be corrupted. If I were you, I'd still try to uninstall/reinstall the game, launch it once, and copy your old save file.

Comment: You might also want to contact the company that makes the game through their email address and offer to send them the corrupted file. They are probably interested in a working product, so this kind of bug report is useful to them. Include a proper report of what you did to your phone between when the game last worked and when it stopped working (software updates, installing other apps, dropping in the toilet etc...) and what you did with the file specifically when you backupped it. Be nice and professional about it and you will find that is a rewarding course of action.

Comment: @simbabque Uh... Bethesda, not a huge company ? Hmmm... Anyway, I agree with the rest of your message.

Comment: Hmmm... I've actually just checked the file details of the vault file while I was trying to copy it off my phone and it is 0KB. I suspect it will be tricky to recover anything from that. :(

Comment: This is now outdated as of patch 1.2, cloud save is possible.

Comment: Cloud save does not sync across multiple devices. Launching the game on another device does not load any cloud data.

Comment: @SkyHiRider Does it work on a single device, i.e after a factory reset ?

Comment: Don't know, didn't try. You can use Dropsync app to back up saves on Android

Comment: @SkyHiRider Doesn't really matter to me, I was jjust checking if you had some info to improve my answer ;)

Comment: At some point they added a backup system. So if your save file is corrupted (0kb) like mine was, you can look in the file location specified in this answer under "Manual backup" where you will hopefully find a VaultX.sav.bkp. It might be out of date but it's better than losing the vault altogether.

Answer (score 6):

On iOS, Fallout Shelter save data does not survive an iPad device wipe. :( (I know this from personal experience.)

A recent iTunes backup should save the day, however.

Comment: Question was specific to Android platform, and gave an Android-specific backup step. I created an answer to cover the iOS side of things. The question title is ambiguous, so I think it makes sense to add this information.

Comment: I see. I edited the answer a bit to hightlight this as well as to format it more as an answer rather than recollection of personal experience. You can roll back the edit, if you don't like it.

Comment: Did the iTunes backup actually worked ?

Answer (score 5):

As of patch 1.2, [unofficial notes here](http://www.gamezone.com/news/fallout-shelter-update-1-2-released-for-ios-and-android-here-s-what-s-new-3426371), cloud saves are available.

> Among the features is the arrival of a mysterious new stranger who can reward you with additional bottlecaps, a more difficult Survival Mode, the ability to save your Vault to the "cloud." Exclusively on the App Store for iOS, you can now get the all-new legendary character Piper from Fallout 4 and five free lunchboxes. Check out all that's new in the video above, and read below for Bethesda's official patch notes.
>
> - New Vault-Tec network protocols are finally in place. Now you can save your Vault to the “cloud,” (no moisture condenser necessary!) and continue any Vault experiment on all of your devices.
> - Some Dwellers are reporting sightings of a mysterious individual in Vaults around the Wasteland. Vault-Tec is offering a bottle cap reward for any positive identification!
> - Faced all the challenges the “normal” Vault simulation can provide? Introducing Survival Mode! More danger, More glory. Make Vault-Tec proud!
> - New Vault-Tec directive – Dwellers have been given authorization to scavenge equipment from dead Raiders. Gear up!
> - Are you an experienced Overseer who has already undergone Vault operational training? Now you can skip the tutorial!
> - In an effort to assist Overseers in running their Vaults more efficiently, Vault-Tec has added a statistics page to the Vault Dweller’s Survival Guide (VDSG).
> - Support added for Russian-speaking Overseers.
> - Continued general maintenance to the Vault simulation.  Because when you speak, Vault-Tec listens!
> - Available exclusively on the App Store, all new legendary character Piper from Fallout 4 and five FREE lunchboxes!

[Bethesda forum thread also stating cloud save available](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1539130-finally-fos-12-update/).

> - New Vault-Tec network protocols are finally in place. Now you can save your Vault to the "cloud," (no moisture condenser necessary!).
> - Some dwellers are reporting strange, some would even say mysterious, sightings in Vaults.
> - Introducing Survival Mode! More danger, More glory. Make Vault-Tec proud!
> - Support added for Russian-speaking Overseers.
> - Continued Maintenance to the Vault simulation. Because when you speak, Vault-Tec listens!
>
> Overseers, to activate the "Cloud" system, you guys must mark the option on Vault List window.